# User Answered a Deleted Question on Another Question

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, comments, deleted-questions

I asked this question a little over a month ago:

[Scrolling through UITableView causes Exception and Crash only on iPhone 5C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748671/scrolling-through-uitableview-causes-exception-and-crash-only-on-iphone-5c)

It received a downvote, and was eventually closed by the Community Moderator.

Another user then tried to answer the deleted question on a different question I asked:

[Nested JSON Objects in Keen.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620330/nested-json-objects-in-keen-io#comment41309755_24620330)

I want to re-open the original deleted question and start a discussion with this user.  How do I inform a moderator I have a valid reason to re-open the question?  I don't want to waste a re-open flag if a moderator doesn't think I have a good reason to re-open the question.

EDIT: I have edited the question to include the relevant code in an attempt to get it reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was never closed.  It was deleted by the automatic cleanup script since it had a negative score, no comments, and no answers after 30 days.

You can flag the post for moderator attention if you feel that the question has merit and should be undeleted; you can reference the comment you receive as evidence of that.

Comment: Thank you for or answer.  I have edited the original question to include the code block where the issue is occurring.